# Android: View by id? (from Widget Provider)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I know only one way to get a view by id:

```
getViewById(R.drawable.imageButton)
```

But how am I supposed to get this imageButton if i don't have an activity (developing a widget application)

I am able to get a context. I suppose it is enough to get the view - context contains only one widget isn't it? And if not - then how to get each widget views ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Widgets you have to work with [RemoteViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html), for example

```
RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
```

[Here](http://nm-blog.sanid.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/android_howto-hellowidget.pdf) you can find a tutorial of how to use them

Comment: Please provide full answer, not just link based ones.

Answer (score 3):

Inside onReceive

```
AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

int[] appWidgetIds = mgr.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, YourWidgetProvider.class));

RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);

rv.setImageViewResource(R.id.yourImageView, R.drawable.yourBitmap);

mgr.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, rv);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can get handle of ImageView. 
But you can use setImageViewBitmap or setImageViewResource or setImageViewUri from RemoteView class to set the bitmap of ImageView.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html

Comment: Are you sure that I cannot get my widget layout?

Comment: I'm not trying to say that I don't beleive you but it sounds strange... especially without androiddev link where they say the same thing