# Android: how to process onClick without an activity?

Tags: android, android-widget

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick

Here it is said that

> For instance, if you specify android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void sayHello(View v) method of your context (typically, your Activity).

I'm intrested in "typically, your Activity"... And what if not typically? I'm creating a widget app so I don't have an activity at all...

Almost forgot..
And the question is: where should I write that sayHello method?

Comment: same question like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528891/android-view-by-id-from-widget-provider

Comment: no. for me it's not the same. Anyway if I knew the answer maybe I would think the same you do. But I don't=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code which is responsible for the invacation:

```
try {
    mHandler = getContext().getClass().getMethod(handlerName, View.class);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find a method " +
        handlerName + "(View) in the activity", e);
}
```

So basiclly it searches in the class which implements the context for the given method. Usually the context is an activity.

Comment: and is it possible to customize that class?.. In case of widget app

Comment: You **never** implement it yourself. This is a task which android has to handle. In case of a app widget I'm not quite sure which context is used to infalte the view. But widgets are special anyway since they has a remote view pattern (sorry didn't do much in that area). I would bet that you shouldn't even try to get `onClick` attribute to work.